# Vite fails to build sveltekit app, returns exit code 1 during prerender

Tags: error-handling, vite, sveltekit

So when I run `npm run build --debug` (using vite), I get the error:

```
[vite-plugin-svelte-kit] Prerendering failed with code 1
error during build:
Error: Prerendering failed with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> ([path to project, omitted])
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
```

I have googled for "[vite-plugin-svelte-kit] Prerendering failed with code 1", but nothing useful turned up. This works fine with `npm run dev` not preview or build. I tried to deploy to Vercel, and this is the same error.

If it helps, my svelte.config.js file:

```js
import preprocess from "svelte-preprocess";
import vercel from "@sveltejs/adapter-vercel"

const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: vercel(),
    },
    preprocess: [
        preprocess({
            scss:{
                prependData:`@import './src/scss/styles.scss';`
            },
            postcss:true,
        }),
    ],
};

export default config;
```

I am using Sass (actually SCSS, but they are mostly the same), and if that is part of the problem that would be a big help because I do get the warning:

```
(30)...warnings when minifying css:
▲ [WARNING] Unexpected "$" [css-syntax-error]
...
```

Comment: If anyone knows what "code 1" means, please tell me.

Comment: I had the same issue, but I got it solved when updating `@sveltejs/adapter-node` to version `1.1.0`. I don't know if you are using that adapter, but worth mentioning.

Comment: Oh ok, that might help

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this issue when trying to build as a static web app, throught trial and error I have found that if I am missing, or have an incorrect src tag on an element that I throw this error during build.
Perhaps a place to start. Really annoying error with not much to go from. I do hava a different config to you though and not using Vercel.

Comment: As an adendum to this, it also throws errors if you attempt to build with a path that doesn't exist for a link or navigation. In my case I was using some CSS templates that have routes such as /about or /contact  and when removed it builds

Comment: Okay, I'll look into it. I still haven't found the problem, but have updated Vite, which gets me trough build, though on Vercel it still fails. So, maybe that might help